# Passing data to universal twig file Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I want to send user data to my univeral header file, which is shown on every page so I can display a "Hi, {{ username }}" message.

How can I do this without getting the data in all controllers of every page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also render data from a totally different controller and action (so just from one place) in your twig template by using:

```
{{ render(controller('AppBundle:Base:myAction')) }}
```

You can read it over here: https://reformatcode.com/code/c/calling-r39s-optim-function-from-within-c-using-rcpp

Comment: Thanks, very helpful! I'm still trying to figure out Symfony.

Answer (score 1):

You can access current user in your twig template via the global variable app, using app.user :

```
{# If user is connected #}
{% if is_granted('ROLE_USER') %}
    Hi, {{ app.user.username }}
{# If user is NOT connected #}
{% else %}
   ...
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 1):

To get the currently logged in user, you can simply write: `{{ app.user }}`. Then you can access any property from there.